# Calling an HTTP handler from C# application throwing exception

Tags: c#, postman

I am attempting to retrieve data from an HTTP handler to my C# app in a similar fashion to Chromes Postman and Advanced rest client.

Eg

```
Target = http://10.113.171.82/handler
Payload =
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<webpage pageID="406" cmdID="GET" cursor="0"/>"
```

This works fine from within Postman or Advanced Rest  Client but fails miserably from a C# app. The latest error is
**The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine.**

I've tried the usual suggestions (KeepAlive False, useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true").

Here's the abbreviated version.

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://10.113.171.82/handler");
string payload = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><webpage pageID=\"406\" cmdID=\"GET\" cursor=\"0\"/>";
byte[] data = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(payload);
myHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
myHttpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
myHttpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
myHttpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
myHttpWebRequest.Accept = "*/*";
myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2;)";
myHttpWebRequest.Timeout = 100000;
myHttpWebRequest.Accept = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
myHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
myHttpWebRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
myHttpWebRequest.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 100000;
myHttpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
Stream requestStream = myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
requestStream.Close();
myHttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

//Error on the GetResponse
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);

pageContent = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

myStreamReader.Close();
responseStream.Close();

myHttpWebResponse.Close();
```

Things to note. If I remove the URLEncoding the error is "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive." Although this seems a bit hit and miss. Also, if I remove /handler from the target I get an HTML response but not what I want. 
Most of the properties have been added in an attempt to find a solution.
I think I'm missing something fundamental!

Answer (score 1):

I think I've discovered the problem. 
The server returns no headers at all. If I enable source debugging I find a null reference exception at 
    System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)

Although this resolves this problem (why it's happening) it simply creates a new problem. How to receive an HTTP request without HTTP/1.0 200 OK